# How to get data from React aplication on Express server to update meta-tags with data fetched from API

Tags: reactjs, express

I am using a React API where I fetch data using an API call. I need this data to be accessible in Express server so that I can update meta-tags, but I haven't found the way to achive this. This is the URL estructure:

```
/post/slug
```

React component where I fetch all the data:

```
const Post = () => {

    const [post, setPost] = useState(null)
    const { slug } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        const urlFetch = 'URL' + slug;

        fetch(urlFetch )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setPost(data));
    }, [slug]);

    if (!post) {
        return (
            <>
                //Loader
            </>
        )
    }

    return (
        <>
            //component
        </>
    );

}

export default Post;
```

In order to change meta-tags dynamically y use Express but I have no idea how can I achieve this., this is server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');

const PORT = 5000;

const app = express();

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build", "index.html");
    await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        data = data
            .replace(/__TITLE__/g, "Home title")
            .replace(/__DESCRIPTION__/g, "Home description");
    
        res.send(data);
    })
})

app.get('/:type/:slug', async (req, res) => {
    const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build", "index.html");
    await fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }

        data = data
            .replace(/__TITLE__/g, "Post title")
            .replace(/__DESCRIPTION__/g, "Post description");
    
        res.send(data);
    })
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./client/build")));

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening to port: ${PORT}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change meta tag simply via using React Helmet which its allow you to update meta tags direct on run time...

for example:

```
<head>
<title>needed Title</title>
<meta name="description" content="description component">
```

you can use this in every component as you want, and update it dynamically via state...

also you can build html component for handling it as a wrapper:

```
function HTML () {
const htmlAttrs = helmet.htmlAttributes.toComponent();
const bodyAttrs = helmet.bodyAttributes.toComponent();

return (
    <html {...htmlAttrs}>
        <head>
            {helmet.title.toComponent()}
            {helmet.meta.toComponent()}
            {helmet.link.toComponent()}
        </head>
        <body {...bodyAttrs}>
            <div id="content">
                // React stuff here
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
);
```

}

so that, now when you post or get you will fetch meta tag dynamic, and nested of replace on express you can just update code to fetch tags and assign it react..and if you need to post data in meta just fetch it from the state and put it in post request..

for more details: [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet)

Comment: Thank you! Is there a full explanation for this case? I´m not sure how I need to deal with the build html component creation.

Comment: I think for basic one, you can ignore it, use the first one in every componet will be the best - for me...since you can control all wrap all compent easy and do any change easy...

for html do it as a wrapper componet....in app.jsx...theres a full example in url in answer...good luck :D